# Is there a way to control windows media center without focus?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, htpc

I would like to set up a new desktop at home with the dual purpose of using it for my regular applications and as an HTPC for the family. In my initial playing around with media center I noticed that it has to have focus for a remote to work. Are there any solutions out there to let my family use the remote to control media center on a second monitor (my tv) while I am still working in the main screen?

If not are there any other HTPC applications out there that will allow me to do this and are better than windows media center?